# compiling .dll while application is running

Tags: c++, dll

Assume this scenario: An application (**app.exe**) is using multiple .dlls. I am debugging a function, **bugged_function()** from one of the .dlls used by the app: **util.dll**. While I am debugging **bugged_function()** from this I realize that something in the code is wrong and changes have to be made.

Steps to perform normally:

**1.** close **app.exe**

**2.** modify code in the function

**3.** recompile util.dll

**4.** rerun **app.exe**

What I want:

**Bypass step 1 and 4**. To do that I need to **unload** in some way, if possible, **util.dll** library so when compiling it can be overridden. The the application must somehow **reload** the library again.

*EDIT 1:*

I do not know how **bugged_function()** is called. Assume that I only have access to the source code of the library **util.dll** used by **app.exe**.

*EDIT 2:*

I am using Visual Studio 2010, and when I debug, I attach to **app.exe** process.

Comment: How is `bugged_function()` called? Through result of `GetProcAddress()`?

Comment: Edit: I'm not sure, since I don't have access to the code. I'll edit the question to highlight this.

Answer (score 3):

If the application is using the dll via [run-time dynamic linking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it could be unloaded (`FreeLibrary` or similar), then reloaded (`LoadLibrary` or similar).

If the application is using the dll via [load-time dynamic linking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I think you're out of luck.

Edit: I misread the question slightly.  Since you can't modify `app.exe`, you'll have to rely on built-in functionality of that application for runtime loading and unloading, if it has it.  That depends totally on the application.

Answer (score 1):

Visual studio can edit and continue. So if you are at a breakpoint, you can make the changes you need to then continue your debugging. Visual studio will compile and apply the changes while maintaining state.

Edit: fixed edit and continue naming.

Comment: If I modify the code while in debug mode, it is saying I need to recompile. Note: I use Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: It does seem to have some odd limitations on what it can just apply and what requires a rebuild. Make sure you are using the /ZI option. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/958x11bc(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @DanLincan : If it says that, that means you either don't have Edit and Continue configured properly, or your linker settings are specifying the wrong debug information format. The docs for configuring Edit and Continue are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esaeyddf(VS.100).aspx). (Note also that there are some limitations regarding when E&C may be used, such as the presence of any `/clr` variant.)